# Smaato iPhone ad in the universal app

Tags: ios

I have universal app and want to integrate Smaato. But Smaato let me create only specified ad - iPad or iPhone. So, can I use smaato iphone ad id in my universal app and will it be handled correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The two views (Phone and Pad) should always use different viewControllers, as they're very different and the Pad version should take advantage of the larger screen. You can specify the banner you want from smaato specifying it in

```
[[SOMABannerView alloc] initWithDimension:kSOMAAdDimensionDefault]
```

in this case, it's using kSOMAAdDimensionDefault for an iPhone ad. Look at the documentation and you will find many more options and sizes.